# Sound over multiple xservers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, xserver

I'm currently using multiple X-Server displays. Is it possible to share the sound which all the programs generate (through pulseaudio) over all displays?

So for example I have a music program on display 1 and I want to hear it when I'm on display 0.

Perhaps one way would be to do a multicast with pulseaudio, but is there a simpler approach?

Comment: (still researching) [linking](http://askubuntu.com/questions/589448/wine-no-sound-at-x-1?noredirect=1#comment818891_589448); I found some tips but couldnt test yet, if interest you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX#Pulseaudio; http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105968/30352

Comment: found solution, play thru TCP! http://askubuntu.com/a/589607/46437