# Wine, no sound at X :1

Tags: sound, xorg, wine, games, pulseaudio

Sound for Wine-1.7.34 works at `:0`

Open a new X session at `:1`
lets make audio possible at `:1` with:

```
usermod -a -G audio $USER      #requires re-login  
pax11publish -D :1 -e
DISPLAY=:1 ck-launch-session
```

Test sound with mplayer (it works, but not through pulseaudio)

```
$ WINEDEBUG=+quartz winecfg /Audio/Test Sound
err:pulse:pulse_contextcallback Context failed: Connection refused
```

How to fix?

Comment: I suspect you were using the default alsa audio output back-end of mplayer. Try with "mplayer -ao pulse" to see if mplayer works with pulseaudio.

Comment: mplayer failed with pulse. So that means pulse will not work at X :1 or you think there may have some way? or.. may be I should make wine work with alsa?

Comment: I don't know what the exact issue is (or why you're even bothering with trying to run something on a different X server and have it output sound like this). It says _connection refused_ though, which seems like a permissions problem with the socket it uses, or similar.

Comment: I found a way to have sound but it have issues: `winetricks sound=alsa` (to undo is necessary edit registry removing that key), the problem is many sounds on the games are missing, some sounds play and many others dont (no idea why); at :0 all sounds play, at :1 (without pulseaudio) the problem happens.

Comment: I run on a different X because of some reasons like: avoid changing screen resolution and messing all other windows; avoid issues with grabbed mouse; there are a few more.

Comment: I also tried to [temporarily disable pulse audio](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio) and test again with alsa, but the sound problems remained (so seems not be a conflict but an alsa limitation?)

Comment: @dobey it worked, the socket tip you gave helped thanks! I am playing from :1 thru TCP! will post what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to play using pulseaudio from `DISPLAY :1` through TCP (without system mode daemon):

I got the instructions from [this blog post](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2014/01/pa-multiple-users/) which got the fix from [here on fedora forums](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=190954).

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.pulse/
echo "load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1" >>~/.pulse/default.pa
echo "default-server = 127.0.0.1" > ~/.pulse/client.conf
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio -D
```